# How to create a dynamic table with vue js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-component

I have a question. How to create a dynamic table with vue js.

I want to render this json file into the table using Vue but it doesn't happen as I want. I want the data in two languages and app_adi but only the latest data is coming. How can I display both?

json file

```
{
   "accounts":{
         "user":{
            "_id":"5a500vlflg0aslf011ld0a25a5",
            "username":"john",
            "id":"59d25992988fsaj19fe31d7",
            "name":"Test",
            "customer":" John Carew",
         },
         "application":[
            {
               "app_id":"5af56pi314-y1i96kdnqs871nih35",
               "language":"es"
            },
            {
               "app_id":"5af56pi314-blvinpgn4c95ywyt8j",
               "language":"en"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

I want to build this table:

```
username customer    language  app_di
john     John Carew   es        5af56pi314-y1i96kdnqs871nih35
                      en        5af56pi314-blvinpgn4c95ywyt8j
```

Comment: you can use for loop to iterate over application array 
for more info https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: Actually, I know what you're saying. However, I want two data on a single td tag. For example, "language": "en", "us" I want these two data in the same cell

Comment: For example: this example https://jsfiddle.net/duax6zy8/346/ How do we write Chuck norris and Yuri boykaya into the same cell without the same string?

Comment: You can use another `v-for` inside of a `<td>`. You can e.g. use a `<span/>` element for this or if you want to no additional markup, you can use `<template/>`. So here's an example: `<td><span v-for="app in row.application">{{ app.app_id }}</span></td>`

Comment: I could not , can you show me your example on jsfiddle please

Comment: You can also put another component inside your td element and iterate the languages in the other component.

Comment: I try to do but I can't, can you show me an example

Answer (score 0):

Preprocess your json in a computed property.

In your example you just need to add the "user" properties to the first "application" item.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      columns: {
        username: 'Name',
        customer: 'Customer',
        language: 'Language',
        app_id: 'App_ID'
      },
      userData: {
        "user": {
          "_id": "5a500vlflg0aslf011ld0a25a5",
          "username": "john",
          "id": "59d25992988fsaj19fe31d7",
          "name": "Test",
          "customer": " John Carew",
        },
        "application": [{
            "app_id": "5af56pi314-y1i96kdnqs871nih35",
            "language": "es"
          },
          {
            "app_id": "5af56pi314-blvinpgn4c95ywyt8j",
            "language": "en"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    tableData() {
      return this.userData.application.map((x, index) => {
        return index === 0 ? Object.assign(x, this.userData.user) : x
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ellisdod/jm3snwxc/2/